# Symfony 4 - KnpPaginatorBundle - This form should not contain extra fields

Tags: php, symfony, pagination

I'm using KnpPaginatorBundle for a page.
In this page, I use a hand-created filter, which gives this

[image]

So if I enter something in the form, it will process the request and show as agreed.
The problem is when I ask to sort by 'ID'.

This problem occurs when I make a filter on the name or service, and I ask to order by ID

I have the following error message:

> This form should not contain extra fields

[image]

What should I do to stop this error?

My controller is :

```
 /**
     * Undocumented function
     * 
     * @Route("/rh3", name="rh_index3")
     *
     * @param PaginatorInterface $paginator
     * @param Request $request
     * @param ObjectManager $manager
     * @param UserRepository $repo
     * @return void
     */
    public function index3(PaginatorInterface $paginator, Request $request, UserRepository $repo)
    {

        $search = new UserSearch();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserSearchType::class, $search);
        $form->handleRequest($request);




        $users = $repo->getUsersSearch($search);

        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $users,
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
            7
        );

        return $this->render('rh/index3.html.twig', [
            'pagination' => $pagination,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

And my Twig:

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}

    <div class="jumbotron">

        <div class="container">
            {{form_start(form)}}
            <div class="form-row align-items-end">
                <div class="col">
                    {{form_row(form.name)}}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    {{form_row(form.service)}}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Rechercher</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            {{form_end(form)}}
        </div>

    </div>

    <table class="table table-hover align-items-center">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Id', 'u.id') }}</th>
                <th>Nom</th>
                <th>Service</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for user in pagination %}
                <tr {% if loop.index is odd %} class="color" {% endif %}>
                    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.fullName}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.groupe.nom}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Voir</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="navigation">
        {{knp_pagination_render(pagination)}}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your UserSearchType add this option:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'allow_extra_fields' => true,
    ));
}
```